# Change default import file from index.ts to index.native.ts

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, visual-studio-code

I'm building a React component library (using TypeScript and styled-components) and I want to reuse as much as possible code between the two targets (web and native).

I have a folder called `styled`, and inside that folder, I have two index files: `index.ts` and `index.native.ts`.

Inside the `index.ts` I have: `export { default as styled } from 'styled-components';` while in the `index.native.ts` I have `export { default as styled } from 'styled-components/native';`

I know **React Native** uses `index.native.ts` instead of `index.ts` during the build process when it is available but I really need to make the IDE (vscode) to understand that, I mean, when I'm building a Button.native.ts the statement: `import { styled } from '../styled'` should import from the `.native` barrel and the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + click should let us to the `.native` file.

I don't know if there is a configuration to change the default import file used as a barrel, I already tried to search in the typescript documentation for some react-native preset but I didn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

It is not related to TypeScript, it is an [open issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/23251) on VSCode GitHub page. Still doesn't have any solution.

Even I didn't find solution on [react native vscode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=msjsdiag.vscode-react-native) plugin.

By my understanding you are working on RNW, so it is not a correct expectation that VSCode understand by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>CLICK</kbd> your meaning is Web or Native side. When it works in development and production so forget about opening right code by click.